# Relation between Temperature and heat current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, conductors

This problem:

[image]

I was able to solve it doing this:

[image]

But I think i have nowhere " exploited " the equivalence given above. How can this be used in this problem?

Comment: i guess you did "exploit' that equivalence when you wrote the first line of your solution.

Comment: got it and put it in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first relation has been derived by using the equivalence given above.

$$\frac {dQ}{dt} = j(\vec r)*4\pi r^2$$
 Putting $$\frac {dT}{dr} =k* j(\vec r)$$
Since $$\frac {dV}{dr} = \vec E(\vec r)$$

We will get the same relation